# What type/types of threading should I use in WPF and c# for my scenario... regular threads, background worker, or thread pool?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, threadpool

I have an order manager application created in C# and WPF. The order manager application needs to communicate back and forth with a shipping application that is written in a completely different shipping language. The method of communication between the programs is an XML file whose EnableShipping attribute is either a 0 or a 1 and a SQL database.

In my order manager application I have button that "Begins shipping" and changes the EnableShipping attribute from a 0 to a 1. The shipping application is looping and reads this value, begins shipping all of the orders whose certain attribute matches a string, changes this attribute to a different string, and marks a different attribute (Status Changed) to 1.

In my order manager application, as of now I have a thread that continually loops and checks the database for orders with a Status Changed attribute of 1, makes the changes to the UI and writes back to the database, Status Changed = 0.

Here is some code to show what my order manager application is doing in the thread.

```
while(true)
        {
            string enabled = null;
            currentInstance = OrderManager.getCurrentInstance();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select OrderNumber, BatchStatus from dbo.Orders where StatusChanged='1'", connection1);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Int64 orderNum = (Int64)reader[0];
                    int index = linqForOrderIndex(orderNum);
                    string batchStatus = (string)reader["BatchStatus"];
                    SqlCommand statusChangedFalse = new SqlCommand("Update dbo.orders Set StatusChanged = '0' where OrderNumber = '" + orderNum + "'", connection2);
                    switch (batchStatus)
                    {
                        case "Untouched":
                            currentInstance.Orders[index].batchStatus = "Untouched";
                            break;
                        case "Batch Ready":
                            currentInstance.Orders[index].batchStatus = "Batch Ready";
                            break;
                        case "Shipped":
                            currentInstance.Orders[index].batchStatus = "Shipped";
                            break;
                        case "Error":
                            currentInstance.Orders[index].batchStatus = "Error";
                            break;
                    }
                    statusChangedFalse.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    reader.Close();
                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                }

                currentInstance.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(
                        delegate()
                        {
                            currentInstance.refreshTreeFilters();
                            currentInstance.refreshOrderCounts();
                            currentInstance.batchReadyView();
                        }
                    )); 
            }
      }
```

So Even if you don't know exactly what is going on in the code, you know that I have to continuously check the database for status changed items, do work on those items in my collection as well as in the database, update the UI, and keep repeating the process.

At first I thought a good old thread would work like my code is doing now, but the UI becomes unresponsive when I am "doing work". I looked at some background worker code online seeing if maybe that would be a good choice for better UI responsiveness, but didn't know if this is a good solution as I need to continuously keep doing work and updating the UI.

Any thoughts or suggestions? appreciate it...

Comment: Use BackgroundWorkers unless there is a reason to do otherwise. Closing as "Not a Real Question" due to the "ask for input" nature.

Comment: In any case, this code posted is also very much *likely not* thread-safe as it looks like the same data is accessed from the background thread and the UI thread at the same time.

Comment: Can I use BackgroundWorkers to loop forever and check the database for statusChanged items?

Comment: No. That would be silly (a BGW is designed for BG-Work->UI-result). So, rule that out and proceed. It still doesn't change my other comments.

Comment: So if I have a thread that runs forever, checks for changes in the database and finds some, then call the backgroundworker functions in the UI-behind code to "DoWork"...Is that the correct way to approach it?

Comment: A BGW represents one "background task". So it would be a new BGW each time you wanted to check the database. Then the Completed Event would update the UI. This inverts the loop from inside to outside the other thread. It also prevents "stacking" of callbacks as a new scan is only started after the previous data is updated. (E.g. the a new BGW is triggered in the Completed event.)

Comment: First find out _why_ your GUI is unresponsive. A Bgw is just another way to use a Thread, not obviously better in this situation. Maybe measure how much time that BeginInvoke stuff takes.

Comment: I think you're right Henk, my BeginInvoke stuff runs through a tree view and refreshes 10-15 filters on a collection as well as updating counts on all the filters. That probably is making the GUI unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use BackGroundWorker with ReportsProgess to send the info to UI thread.  You can pass an object.  Also implement cancellation so you you don't shut down stream.

[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx)

The other option is there is a way to get SQL notification.

[Query Notifications in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)